# how to create link for one user id from datatable and view only that user id detail in next page?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, html-table

I have a function **manage_child** which it is in a datatables that show all children details. My problem is I want to view only one child details at another pages. I have tried to implement this example of code in my function but it didnt work since I call it like this:

```
`<td><a href="?pages=child_view"</a><?php_e($child_id); ?></td>`
```

I have link the page where the details should go but it didn't work.  I am still in my basic using php and I use mysqli for the database.

**This is the example that I tried to implement in my code but still doesn't work.**

```
echo "<td><a href=Edit_Employee.php?".$row[id].">".$row[id]."</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=Edit_Employee.php?".$row[id].">".$row[l_name]."</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=Edit_Employee.php?".$row[id].">".$row[f_name]."</a></td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=Edit_Employee.php?".$row[id].">".$row[ssn]."</a></td>";
```

**this is my code**

```html
function manage_child(){
     
    $query = query("SELECT * FROM register_child");
    
    confirm($query);
    
    ?>

   <div class='container-fluid'>
       <div class='row'>
           <h1 class="page-header">Children
           <small>Information</small>
           </h1>
           <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
               <table width="50%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>No</th>
                           <th>CHild ID</th>
                           <th>Child IC</th>
                           <th>Name</th>
                           <th>Address</th>
                           <th>Mother name</th>
                           
                           
                      </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       
                       
                  
                       <?php
    
                        $bil = 0;
                        while($row = fetch_array($query)) {
                            
                            $password            = $row['ic_no'];
                            $child_id            = $row['child_id'];
                            $child_name          = $row['child_name'];
                            $address             = $row['address'];
                            $mother_name         = $row['mother_name'];
                          
                            $bil++;
                            
                     ?> 
                       <tr class="odd gradeX">
                           <td><?php echo $bil; ?></td>
                           <td><?php _e($password);?></td>
                           <td><a href="?pages=child_view"</a><?php _e($child_id); ?></td>
                           <td><?php _e($child_name); ?></td>    
                           <td><?php _e($address); ?></td>
                           <td><?php _e($mother_name); ?></td>
                          
                           
                         
                                  
                            <?php
                         
     }// End of while
                             ?>
                       
                    </tbody>
               </table>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>

<?php

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific error message or behavior that led you to believe that it doesn't work? `<td><a href="?pages=child_view"</a><?php _e($child_id); ?></td>`  is missing the closing `>' after you open and you're not passing a child id

Comment: the hyperlink work on the child id at datatables and go to the desired page, but i have got an error message like this at child_view pages --> **Notice: Undefined index: child_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\PSM_IMUNISASI\app\views\templates-admin\form-admin\child_view.php on line 49**

Comment: @Kisaragi this is what the code in child_view look like.. i just play with the code by put it in a form to show if the data is pass in.. but got an error message like i have mention above, should i put a query declaration or something? im still newbie with this php..